# Multi-site simple search not working

Tags: search, multi-site-manager

I am new to expression engine and setup multiple sites using MSM. All the sites having simple search form to search across the channels. When i search with the master site the search working perfectly, But when i search through the sites other than master it redirects me to no result page.

```
{exp:search:simple_form
    channel="news|business|travel"
    result_page="search/results"
    no_result_page="search/no_results"
    search_in="everywhere"}

    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="search" value="" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" required /> 

    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>

{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Comment: Why do your inputs have `id`s, `name`s, and `class`es? Do you have a lot of ill-conceived jQuery form plugins in play? Selector wise, you only need `name`, and class is ok to add too.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting which site you want to search in, otherwise it will only search the current site. If it can't find those channels, you get no results.

```
channel="site_name:news|site_name:business|site_name:travel"
```

MSM is nice. But when you want to pull data from one site into another, you need to specify where the data comes from.

Comment: Still redirecting to no_results page. According to your suggestion i had made the following changes to the search form 
{exp:search:simple_form channel="default_site:news|default_site:business|default_site:travel" result_page="search/results" no_result_page="search/no_results" search_in="everywhere"}